# Wrong result using $gte and $lt operators in mongo for date field

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongo so I am hoping I am missing something simple here. I have 28 documents with the following values of create_timestamp -

```
{ "id" : NumberLong(96), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-18T09:00:00Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(97), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(104), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(106), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(109), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(110), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(120), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(121), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(122), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(124), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(125), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(126), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(128), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(129), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(130), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(132), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(136), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(140), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(145), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
{ "id" : NumberLong(150), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-20T15:37:51.575Z") }
```

I am querying for all documents with create_timestamp >= ISODate("2017-09-19") AND 
create_timestamp < ISODate("2017-09-20"). I am expecting to see none. However I see this.

> db.transfer_order.find( { $and: [ {"create_timestamp": { $gte: ISODate("2017-09-19")}, "create_timestamp": { $lt: ISODate("2017-09-20")}}]}, {_id: 0, id: 1, create_timestamp: 1})

```
{ "id" : NumberLong(96), "create_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-18T09:00:00Z") }
```

Why is this happening? Why this is query returning this document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the first `create_timestamp` key value with second.

So effectively you are querying

```
db.transfer_order.find( 
{ $and: [ {"create_timestamp": { $lt: ISODate("2017-09-20")}}]}, 
{id: 1, create_timestamp: 1})
```

You can use implicit anding when query same key for multiple values.

```
db.transfer_order.find( 
{"create_timestamp": { $gte: ISODate("2017-09-19"), $lt: ISODate("2017-09-20")}}, 
{id: 1, create_timestamp: 1})
```

Using explicit anding

```
db.transfer_order.find( 
{ $and: [ {"create_timestamp": { $gte: ISODate("2017-09-19")}}, {"create_timestamp": { $lt: ISODate("2017-09-20")}}]}, 
{id: 1, create_timestamp: 1})
```

More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/